# i can only play one audio file in python using replit

Tags: python, replit

I want to play two different music at two different time but it wont work.

I used this code

```
from replit import audio

audio = audio.playfile("sample-music.mp3")
```

and it worked but when I tried it again to play 2 songs. I did this

```
import time
from replit import audio 

audio = audio.playfile("sample-music.mp3")
time.sleep(5)
audio = audio.playfile("sample-music2.mp3")
```

I also tried this

```
import time
from replit import audio 

audio = audio.playfile("sample-music.mp3")
time.sleep(5)
audio1 = audio.playfile("sample-music2.mp3")
```

and those didn't work so then I tried

```
import time
from replit import audio 

source = audio.playfile("sample-music.mp3")
time.sleep(5)
source1 = audio.playfile("sample-music2.mp3")
```

and that still didn't work.

Comment: Don't call variables as the name of the library (audio)

Comment: I've tried that already

Comment: @Landon use a different name

Comment: like I tried ```
import time
from replit import audio 

source = audio.playfile("sample-music.mp3")
time.sleep(5)
source1 = audio.playfile("sample-music2.mp3")
```

Comment: @DarkKnight i did that

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov i did that